# Is it possible to scale Chart.js background Image

Tags: html, chart.js

Is it possible to scale Chart.js background Image so that when the page is resized, the background image is also resized?

Followed the chartjs.org example, but it doesn't resize either.

I've tried CSS on the image object...

Could possibly tie image to  around chart that sizes with page.

Suggestions?

```js
//setup block
const data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: "Elevation",
    radius: 0,
    borderWidth: 2,
    pointBorderColor: 'blue',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'red',
    data: [{
      x: "03/02/2022",
      y: "659.63"
    }, {
      x: "03/03/2022",
      y: "659.6"
    }, {
      x: "03/04/2022",
      y: "659.6"
    }, {
      x: "03/05/2022",
      y: "659.63"
    }, {
      x: "03/06/2022",
      y: "659.81"
    }, {
      x: "03/07/2022",
      y: "659.86"
    }, {
      x: "03/08/2022",
      y: "659.99"
    }, {
      x: "03/09/2022",
      y: "660.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/10/2022",
      y: "660.38"
    }, {
      x: "03/11/2022",
      y: "660.39"
    }, {
      x: "03/12/2022",
      y: "660.78"
    }, {
      x: "03/13/2022",
      y: "660.95"
    }, {
      x: "03/14/2022",
      y: "660.95"
    }, {
      x: "03/15/2022",
      y: "661.01"
    }, {
      x: "03/16/2022",
      y: "661.48"
    }, {
      x: "03/17/2022",
      y: "661.39"
    }, {
      x: "03/18/2022",
      y: "661.24"
    }, {
      x: "03/19/2022",
      y: "661.34"
    }, {
      x: "03/20/2022",
      y: "661.44"
    }, {
      x: "03/21/2022",
      y: "661.34"
    }, {
      x: "03/22/2022",
      y: "661.12"
    }, {
      x: "03/23/2022",
      y: "661.27"
    }, {
      x: "03/24/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/25/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/26/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/27/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/28/2022",
      y: "661.52"
    }, {
      x: "03/29/2022",
      y: "661.53"
    }, {
      x: "03/30/2022",
      y: "661.44"
    }, {
      x: "03/31/2022",
      y: "661.36"
    }, {
      x: "04/01/2022",
      y: "661.0"
    }, {
      x: "04/02/2022",
      y: "660.68"
    }, {
      x: "04/03/2022",
      y: "660.41"
    }, {
      x: "04/04/2022",
      y: "660.247"
    }, {
      x: "04/05/2022",
      y: "660.31"
    }, {
      x: "04/06/2022",
      y: "660.46"
    }, {
      x: "04/07/2022",
      y: "660.7"
    }, {
      x: "04/08/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }, {
      x: "04/09/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }, {
      x: "04/10/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }, {
      x: "04/11/2022",
      y: "660.85"
    }, {
      x: "04/12/2022",
      y: "660.87"
    }, {
      x: "04/13/2022",
      y: "660.83"
    }, {
      x: "04/14/2022",
      y: "660.75"
    }, {
      x: "04/15/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'blue'
  }]
};

//plugin block
const chartAreaBorder = {
  id: 'chartAreaBorder',
  beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        left,
        top,
        width,
        height
      }
    } = chart;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.borderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = options.borderWidth;
    ctx.setLineDash(options.borderDash || []);
    ctx.lineDashOffset = options.borderDashOffset;
    ctx.strokeRect(left, top, width, height);
    ctx.restore();
  }
};

const image = new Image();
image.src = 'castle.png';
const imgPlugin = {
  id: 'custom_canvas_background_image',
  beforeDraw: (chart) => {
    if (image.complete) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const {
        top,
        left,
        width,
        height
      } = chart.chartArea;
      const x = left + width / 2 - image.width / 2;
      const y = top + height / 2 - image.height / 2;
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
    } else {
      image.onload = () => chart.draw();
    }
  }
};

var GradientBgPlugin = {
  beforeDraw: function(chart, args, options) {
    const ctx = chart.ctx;
    const canvas = chart.canvas;
    const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
    // Chart background
    var gradientBack = canvas.getContext("2d").createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250);
    gradientBack.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)");
    gradientBack.addColorStop(1, "rgba(200, 204, 255, 0.7)");
    ctx.fillStyle = gradientBack;
    ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, chartArea.top - chartArea.bottom);
  }
};

//config block
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "HARTWELL PROJECT ",
        font: {
          size: 20
        }
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM yyyy'
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Date'
        }
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          position: 'left',
          display: true,
          text: 'Elevation (FT-MSL)'
        }
      }
    },
    chartAreaBorder: {
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 10,
      //borderDash: [5, 5],
      borderDashOffset: 5
    },
    imgPlugin: {}
  },
  plugins: [chartAreaBorder, imgPlugin, GradientBgPlugin]
};

// render block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```css
.chartBox {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="chartBox">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When drawing the image inside the `beforeDraw` hook, you should should specify its `width` and `height` depending on the size of the `canvas`.

```
const x = left + width / 2 - height / 2;
const y = top + height / 2 - height / 2;
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, height, height);
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: "Elevation",
    radius: 0,
    borderWidth: 2,
    pointBorderColor: 'blue',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'red',
    data: [{
      x: "03/02/2022",
      y: "659.63"
    }, {
      x: "03/03/2022",
      y: "659.6"
    }, {
      x: "03/04/2022",
      y: "659.6"
    }, {
      x: "03/05/2022",
      y: "659.63"
    }, {
      x: "03/06/2022",
      y: "659.81"
    }, {
      x: "03/07/2022",
      y: "659.86"
    }, {
      x: "03/08/2022",
      y: "659.99"
    }, {
      x: "03/09/2022",
      y: "660.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/10/2022",
      y: "660.38"
    }, {
      x: "03/11/2022",
      y: "660.39"
    }, {
      x: "03/12/2022",
      y: "660.78"
    }, {
      x: "03/13/2022",
      y: "660.95"
    }, {
      x: "03/14/2022",
      y: "660.95"
    }, {
      x: "03/15/2022",
      y: "661.01"
    }, {
      x: "03/16/2022",
      y: "661.48"
    }, {
      x: "03/17/2022",
      y: "661.39"
    }, {
      x: "03/18/2022",
      y: "661.24"
    }, {
      x: "03/19/2022",
      y: "661.34"
    }, {
      x: "03/20/2022",
      y: "661.44"
    }, {
      x: "03/21/2022",
      y: "661.34"
    }, {
      x: "03/22/2022",
      y: "661.12"
    }, {
      x: "03/23/2022",
      y: "661.27"
    }, {
      x: "03/24/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/25/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/26/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/27/2022",
      y: "661.29"
    }, {
      x: "03/28/2022",
      y: "661.52"
    }, {
      x: "03/29/2022",
      y: "661.53"
    }, {
      x: "03/30/2022",
      y: "661.44"
    }, {
      x: "03/31/2022",
      y: "661.36"
    }, {
      x: "04/01/2022",
      y: "661.0"
    }, {
      x: "04/02/2022",
      y: "660.68"
    }, {
      x: "04/03/2022",
      y: "660.41"
    }, {
      x: "04/04/2022",
      y: "660.247"
    }, {
      x: "04/05/2022",
      y: "660.31"
    }, {
      x: "04/06/2022",
      y: "660.46"
    }, {
      x: "04/07/2022",
      y: "660.7"
    }, {
      x: "04/08/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }, {
      x: "04/09/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }, {
      x: "04/10/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }, {
      x: "04/11/2022",
      y: "660.85"
    }, {
      x: "04/12/2022",
      y: "660.87"
    }, {
      x: "04/13/2022",
      y: "660.83"
    }, {
      x: "04/14/2022",
      y: "660.75"
    }, {
      x: "04/15/2022",
      y: "660.73"
    }],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'blue'
  }]
};

//plugin block
const chartAreaBorder = {
  id: 'chartAreaBorder',
  beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        left,
        top,
        width,
        height
      }
    } = chart;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.borderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = options.borderWidth;
    ctx.setLineDash(options.borderDash || []);
    ctx.lineDashOffset = options.borderDashOffset;
    ctx.strokeRect(left, top, width, height);
    ctx.restore();
  }
};

const image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7tJH.png';
const imgPlugin = {
  id: 'custom_canvas_background_image',
  beforeDraw: (chart) => {
    if (image.complete) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const {
        top,
        left,
        width,
        height
      } = chart.chartArea;
      const x = left + width / 2 - height / 2;
      const y = top + height / 2 - height / 2;
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, height, height);
    } else {
      image.onload = () => chart.draw();
    }
  }
};

var GradientBgPlugin = {
  beforeDraw: function(chart, args, options) {
    const ctx = chart.ctx;
    const canvas = chart.canvas;
    const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
    // Chart background
    var gradientBack = canvas.getContext("2d").createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250);
    gradientBack.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)");
    gradientBack.addColorStop(1, "rgba(200, 204, 255, 0.7)");
    ctx.fillStyle = gradientBack;
    ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom, chartArea.right - chartArea.left, chartArea.top - chartArea.bottom);
  }
};

//config block
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "HARTWELL PROJECT ",
        font: {
          size: 20
        }
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM yyyy'
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Date'
        }
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          position: 'left',
          display: true,
          text: 'Elevation (FT-MSL)'
        }
      }
    },
    chartAreaBorder: {
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 10,
      //borderDash: [5, 5],
      borderDashOffset: 5
    },
    imgPlugin: {}
  },
  plugins: [chartAreaBorder, imgPlugin, GradientBgPlugin]
};

// render block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="chartBox">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Adjusted Height & Width to scale smaller than chart height .                                           
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'castle.png';
const imgPlugin = {
  id: 'custom_canvas_background_image',
  beforeDraw: (chart) => {
    if (image.complete) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const {top, left, width, height} = chart.chartArea;
      const x = left + width / 2 - height / 2;
      const y = top + height / 2 - height / 3;
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, .9*height, .7*height);
    } else {
      image.onload = () => chart.draw();
    }
  }
};.     //